# Use `[` in *apply

Tags: r

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious in base `R` itself. I want to subset a matrix by its columns based on indices stored in a list.

```
m <- matrix(1:50L, ncol = 5)
l <- lapply(0:3, `+`, 1:2)
> l
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 3 4

[[4]]
[1] 4 5
```

I want a list of matrices as below -

```
list(m[, l[[1]]], m[, l[[2]]], m[, l[[3]]], m[, l[[4]]])
```

I tried `lapply(l, '[', m)`, but that obviously didn't work because `'['` works on `m` like a vector. How can make it work on `m` like a matrix and specify the index 2? I also tried `apply(X = do.call(rbind, l), MARGIN = 1, FUN = '[', m)` but that didn't work either.

I know I can define a function `f` as below; but that feels hacky.

```
f <- function(ind){m[, ind]}
lapply(l, f)
```

Is there any clever way I can avoid defining `f` or am I being unrealistic in not working with `f`?

Comment: why do you find this hacky ? `lapply(l, function(x) m[,x])`

Comment: because it involves the defining an intermediate function which is otherwise unnecessary.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm asking too much?

Comment: you can also try `library(tidyverse);
purrr:map(l, ~m[,.])` or `m[,unlist(l)]` if you don't need a list in the end.